# select the highest value the second time in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a SQL exercise: for all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie.

My solution is here and it works, but I think that should be a smarter way to get this solution. After few checks I inserted the condition "LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1" at the end of the code because i saw at first sight that the result I wanted was that one. My problem is that I think my approach doesn't automate my query. Any suggestion to improve my code?

```
 SELECT name, title
 FROM Rating
 JOIN Reviewer 
 ON Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID
 JOIN Movie 
 ON Movie.mID = Rating.mID
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY ratingDate DESC 
 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

MY new query is:

```
SELECT
    name, title
FROM
     Rating
JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID
JOIN Movie    ON Movie.mID = Rating.mID
     WHERE
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM Rating   later_higher
           WHERE later_higher.rid = Rating.rid
             AND later_higher.mid  = Rating.mid
             AND later_higher.stars > Rating.stars
             AND later_higher.ratingDate > Rating.ratingDate
         )
         AND EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM Rating   earlier_lower
           WHERE earlier_lower.rid = Rating.rid
             AND earlier_lower.mid = Rating.mid
             AND earlier_lower.stars < Rating.stars
             AND earlier_lower.ratingDate < Rating.ratingDate
        )
```

Comment: What about if a review reviews three times?  If they score it as `70% then 80% then 90%` do you want to know about this twice, or just once?  If they score it `70%, 90%, 60%` do you want to know about it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a review if...

- There was an earlier review with a lower score
- There wasn't a later review with a higher score  (that later review WOULD return)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fbff4/1

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  reviews
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM reviews   later_higher
               WHERE later_higher.reviewer_id = reviews.reviewer_id
                 AND later_higher.film_id     = reviews.film_id
                 AND later_higher.score       > reviews.score
                 AND later_higher.review_date > reviews.review_date
             )
  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM reviews   earlier_lower
               WHERE earlier_lower.reviewer_id = reviews.reviewer_id
                 AND earlier_lower.film_id     = reviews.film_id
                 AND earlier_lower.score       < reviews.score
                 AND earlier_lower.review_date < reviews.review_date
             )
```

You can then join on any other tables you like, to get film names, reviewer names, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot. Please,  later_higher and earlier_lower, are they new columns you are creating?

Comment: They're aliases. So I can check a table against itself.

Comment: I have just added (JOIN Reviewer 
ON Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID
     JOIN Movie 
     ON Movie.mID = Rating.mID;) at the end of your query and changed film_id, reviewer_id, score, review_date, with mID, rID, with their name from the tables, etc. It complain with JOIN. But it worked for my previous query

Comment: reviews is also an alias? I am trying to adapt your code with my tables and doesn't recognize reviews

Comment: Include your whole new query in your  question as an edit.

Comment: I have done this 


SELECT name, title
FROM (SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE....) JOINT Rating...as in my previous post. It doesn't work, it complain with join. Please could be clearer in regard to the the syntax. There might be something that I cannot see.

Comment: Please put the Whole query in your Question as an Edit

Comment: just put the new query in my question as an edit. Thanks

Comment: Try it now (I'm on my phone, so corrections are hard at the moment)

Comment: Correct! Cool! Thanks a lot. Not yet clear to me the use of exist and not exist

Comment: please, could you clarify what exactly Exist and NOT exist do.

Comment: Checks if the sub query contains any rows or not.  No row = doesn't exist. Rows = dies exist.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name, title FROM(SELECT name, title, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
 re.reviewer_id, re.film_id ORDER BY re.score DESC) seq
 FROM Rating ra
 LEFT JOIN Reviewer re ON ra.rID = re.rID
 LEFT JOIN Movie m ON ra.mID = m.mID
) a WHERE a.seq = 1;
```

This partitions the reviews based on the reviewer and film, then sorts the score based on the highest. So a reviewer could have reviewed multiple films, but you need the highest scores per film, he/she reviewed.

Comment: I need the highest score voted the second time. Therefore should appear also an order by ratingDate

Comment: And it's MySQL.  Unless the OP specifies MySQL 8.0+ then you can't use windowed / analytic functions.

Comment: @Annalix: I don't really think ordering by the date matters, this is because per time it will give you the highest score per reviewer, even if the same movie is reviewed by the same reviewer 100 times

Comment: @MatBailie, I presumed the SQL illustrating the question was written in MS-SQL, however, I can give you the snippet in MySQL

Comment: Ordering by time matters :  If the sequence is HIGH then LOW the OP doesn't want that to be returned.  The OP specifically wants cases where the second rating is higher than the first rating.

Comment: Also, this will return cases where a review only reviewed a film Once.  The OP specifically wants cases where the same film was reviewed by the same reviewer twice...

Comment: @MatBailie: For the first concern you raised, that's why there is a PARTITION BY re.reviewer_id and re.film_id. The second concern, has been addressed using ORDER BY re.score DESC, so whether it's high or low, the score is sorted in DESCENDING order

Comment: @Dickson I am testing your query and I have: Query failed to execute: near '(': syntax error. But parenthesis look ok.

Comment: @Annalix, apologies, I missed the () at the ROW_NUMBER, but it's updated now

Comment: @Dickson thanks but again the same error. I tried by using parenthesis for FROM Rating ra. But again same error

Comment: @Dickson same error. I don't understand the second FROM to which select is referred.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171266/discussion-between-dickson-and-annalix).

Comment: You're still just selecting the highest scoring review. That's not what the OP asks for. The op is looking for cases where the reviewer increases their score on a second review. If there is no second review, none of the reviews should be returned. If the second review scores lower, none of the reviews should be returned. Your answer is to a different question.